# In Objective-C, how do you declare/use a global variable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables

I have been researching this problem for a long time, and I can't seem to find the answer to this question. I am fairly new to iPhone programming, so sorry if this is a stupid question. If anyone has just specific code to post showing how this can be done, that will be very helpful.

Comment: Hehe... found this on google! coincidence !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C, so just do it the C way:

```
int globalX = 100;
```

And header file:

```
extern int globalX;
```

Comment: So where does that int globalX = 100; go?  Again, sorry if this is a stupid question :)

Comment: no not stupid.  It goes in your .m file, outside of the @implementation block

Comment: It can go almost anywhere in any one .m file, even inside an implementation block (but outside any method or function scope).  I usually put them just after the imports in my app delegate, making that into a pseudo-singleton data model for globals.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I didn't want to get technical, but I put them outside of the @implementation block since they really don't belong to the class ( i guess you could make the argument for simulating class variables with them).  But yes, they can go almost anywhere.

Comment: Probably overkill, but for the few times I've had to do this and needed application wide globals I just declare them in a file called `globals.h` and #import it in the .pch file.

Comment: @Abizern that is what I did as well, and it's a pretty good programming habit (it keeps your code more organized for when you need a lot of global variables).

Comment: @darren - Yes, I emulate simple class variables by instantiating static global variables inside my implementation blocks (and using one implementation block per file so that file scope equals class definition scope.)

Answer (score 2):

You do it exactly the way you would in C.  Here's a simple example:

```
int myGlobal = 3;
```

Comment: I don't know any C...but where would you put that declaration to make it a global variable?

Comment: Then why are you bothering with Objective-C? It's C with objects. You need to know C before you can be effective with Objective-C.

Comment: Well, I started learning Objective-C using a book which assumed that you were new to programming altogether, and pretty much started by teaching the basics of C.

Comment: @Lenny K, to make it global you can put it anywhere that's not inside a function or method.

Comment: I see.  And any class that imports the class I put my declaration in will be able to use that variable?

Comment: put it on the top of your .m file after @implementation A

Comment: @Lenny K - if you want to use the variable in other compilation units, you're going to need to have an `extern` declaration visible to those compilation units.  Check out @darren's answer.

Comment: @Carl Norum: Okay, so I just want to make sure I understand everything. To make a global variable accessible to other classes, I would need to import the class with the global variable and type `extern (my variable)` in the header file of the class that wants to use the variable, right?

Comment: If you use `extern` you don't need to import anything.  I think you need to go learn C.

Comment: Okay I see.  Thank you for your help!  Yes, I think you are right, I will look into getting a book on C.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this's more clearly answer. In my case, I want to create a global class but:

I DONT'T WANT:

```
[GlobalResource shareInstance].bgrMenuFileName;
```

I WANT:

```
R.bgrMenuFileName
```

Do somethings like this!
In GlobalResource.h file:

```
@class GlobalResource;

extern GlobalResource * R;

@interface GlobalResource: NSObject
+ (void) loadGlobalResources;
@end
```

In GlobalResource.m file:

```
// you must redeclare R 
GlobalResource *R;
// then init it

@implementation GlobalResouce
+ (void) loadGlobalResources
{
     R = [[GlobalResource alloc] init];
}
- (id)init
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
          // your init
     }
     return self;
}
@end
```

Then, call loadGlobalResources when your app load:

```
[GlobalResource loadGlobalResources];
```

and import to Prefix.pch for using R anywhere in your project.

```
#import "GlobalResource.h"
```

Use it:

```
CCSprite *s = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:R.bgrMenuFileName];
//...
```